# Как запретить WordPress редактору удалять ссылки?

Tags: wordpress, url

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда при переключении между визуальным редактором и текстовым, удаляются ссылки.

**Удаляются:**

- В button `<button href="/link" data-toggle="modal">Кнопка</button>`
- И когда в чистом виде  `<a href="/link" data-toggle="modal">Кнопка</a>`
  бывает еще что span иногда чистится.

Как этого избежать?

Comment: У `button` нет атрибута `href` - поэтому удаляется, иначе код станет невалидным

Comment: @mihdan тогда почему ссылки удаляются  `a` ?

Comment: Так ссылки или span?

Comment: Может, вы просто пихаете ссылки туда, куда их запрещено пихать?

Comment: @andreymal ну если это не валидно это одно дело, но запрещено это абстрактное понятие или я ошибаюсь.

Comment: span очищается у wp если не указан никакой атрибут, например добавьте класс и span не удалится. У button нет атрибута href это не валидно и поэтому удаляется href, если нужна ссылка значить просто нужно использовать <a href=“”>. За вас уже все придумали.

Comment: Тут можно прям анекдоты придумывать: один сидит и думает как wp запретить удалять ссылки в button, потому что мне так хочется, а второй сидит и думает, как запретить некоторым «разработчикам» пихать атрибут href в тег button?

Comment: @eugene_v прям в точку)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прям так сильно надо, то нужно расширить TinyMCE при помощи `valid_elements`:

```
/**
 * Разрешаем все атрибуты для всех тегов
 */
function so_936041( $init ) {
    $opts = '*[*]';
    $init['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;

    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'so_936041' );
```

Comment: Речь идет про Gutenberg?

Comment: Нет, я отключил Гутенберг через функцию, и пользуюсь стандартными редакторами, которые были до выпуска пятого вордпреса.

Comment: Стандартный редактор WordPress - это TinyMCE, поэтому для него работают все правила оригинального TinyMCE

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko помогло?

Comment: А что это за номер `so_936041` ?

Comment: so - stack overflow, 936041 - номер вопроса